# Flutter - Insecure socket connections are disallowed by platform: 10.0.2.2

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, socketexception, dio

Since today whenever I try to login my application I get the following error thrown by the Dio package: *SocketException: Insecure socket connections are disallowed by platform: 10.0.2.2*

I use the following settings to connect:

```
static BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: "http://10.0.2.2:3000", // on android emulator
    connectTimeout: 5000,
    receiveTimeout: 3000)
```

And consequently something along the lines of (where I have authentication set-up and functioning properly at /user/login):

```
var apiLogin = api.dio;
try {
Response response = await apiLogin.post("/user/login",
          options: Options(contentType: "application/json"),
          data: {"email": email, "password": password});
} on DioError catch (e) {
throw Exception([e]);
}
```

I have a Node server running on port 3000 which is connected to (containerized) mongodb. When trying the authentication, it immediately has the DioError and I haven't been able to find the cause anywhere online.

Does anyone know what this error is related to?

**EDIT [ANSWER]**

Thanks to [@lyrics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6467637/lyrics) for pointing me in the right direction:
From API level 27 and higher, usesCleartextTraffic defaults to false, consequently blocking outgoing http requests, requiring HTTPS.

The solution was to add the following to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

as stated in [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600#50834600)

source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a similar issue with Flutter running on ios Simulator and Android emulator:

```
SocketException: Insecure socket connections are disallowed by platform:
```

Inside the Flutter project go to :

To enable in Ios:

**ios folder -> runner folder -> info.plist**

Then add the following lines to enable HTTP requests:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

To enable in Android:

**Android folder -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml**

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

then add the following line inside application tag:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

First add-in AndroidManifest file

add this line in the end before closing tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

add this line in the beginning
find this tag and add it first in it

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you newly upgraded to Android 10, Well you probably didn't know that HTTPS is the default connection protocol starting with Android 9 and that all connection not using Https will fail.
Read more https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

See this answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/6467637

Answer (score 0):

I was making a call to-
Response response = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata');

Instead of **http** I simply replaced it to **https** and it was fixed.

The new request was-
Response response = await get('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata');

This fixed the issue for me.